# How to do reset/wipe on galaxy nexus with encrypted data

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption

My galaxy nexus, rooted, open bootloader, was running cyanogen mod 10.2 with encrypted data.  I tried to wipe and sideload 11 maguro onto it, and install hung on fixing fs_size in crypto footer.

On rebooting it hung on the cyanogen face.  I wiped a few more things and tried to put 10.2 back on and now the encryption password does not work anymore. So I cant boot the device.

I saw that a total wipe and restart is possible, but Im not sure how.  Sideloading another ROM I am guessing wont help anyway since I cant boot past the encrytion screen as my password is not being accepted.

When I boot into recovery I use clockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.7

What is the best method to start again with my device, to get some type of OS working on it?

My options from my recovery menu
- reboot
-install zip
- wipe data/factory reset  (next menu only asks to wipe data)
- wipe cache partition
- backup and reestore (all involving the /sdcard which it cant mount)
-mounts and storage (the next menu does allow for format /system & /factory - but not sure what that will do?)
- advanced (reboots and logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, boot into fastboot by holding down both volume keys and pressing the power key, then start recovery and do a factory reset.

Comment: yes I can get into recovery mode, but my recovery gives me 7 options.  One is wipe/factory reset.  but that menu just says this will wipe all user data no yes or go back.  The yes fails to mount a few drives and basically does nothing...  Is there another way to do a factory reset?

Comment: I was able to install the TWRP recovery image which I found better than the clockwork.  The factory reset failed, but I wiped everything including the encryption, and then the factory reset worked.